# Document interaction controller shows options but when tapped on any option just hides menu

Tags: ios, objective-c, uidocumentinteraction

I am using the below code and getting true, but when tapping any option from the available,  just hides the menu which is presented rather than opening the respective app.

```
    self.docController = [ UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL: fileUrl ];

    BOOL result = [ self.docController presentOpenInMenuFromRect: CGRectMake(425, self.frame.origin.y+20, 50, 50) inView: [self superview] animated: YES ];

    if(!result)
        [appDelegate showTost:@"No application available to open this file!" :[appDelegate currentViewOfCurrentScreen]];
```